# 起動直後のCPUはどのようにしてBIOSにたどり着くのでしょうか？

Tags: x86, bios

起動直後にBIOSプログラムを実行するためには、BIOS ROMのアドレス0xffff0から起動する必要があります。AMDやintelの仕様書にはそう書かれていますが、私は納得していません。納得できないのは、CPUの初期信号を発行してから、BIOSの0xffff0を実行するまでの過程が書かれていないからです。どなたか、その間に何が起こっているのか教えてください。

私自身の考えでは、インとアウト命令でBIOSに行くことを考えましたが、それではセキュリティやパフォーマンスが低下してしまいます。CPUからBIOSへ直接つながる専用の回路も考えましたが、なぜlinuxやwindowsのosからbiosのアップデートやROMの内容が読み込みが可能なのかと考えました。上記の２つのパターンではないと思いました......
BIOSをいじれないのは寂しいですね。

Comment: 何に納得できないのかよくわかりませんでした。CPUとはメモリの内容を読み込んで実行する装置です。そして電源投入時にCS:EIP=F000:0000FFF0Hで初期化されているため、物理アドレス000FFFF0Hに書かれている命令が実行される、そこでPCメーカーはそのアドレスにBIOSコードを配置する、それだけなことと思います。

Comment: こんな情報 [システムマネジメントモード - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%B7%E3%82%B9%E3%83%86%E3%83%A0%E3%83%9E%E3%83%8D%E3%82%B8%E3%83%A1%E3%83%B3%E3%83%88%E3%83%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%83%89) もあるので、理屈と言うかそう言いたい感覚は分かりますが、それを知ることが出来る/知っている必要があるのはインテルやx86互換CPUを開発するベンダーの関係者だけでしょう。CPUの利用者は仕様書に書かれている内容を基にハード/ソフトを作成・利用していけば良くて、知り得ない情報が手に入らないことに悶々とするよりは公開された情報を活用することに注力した方が良いと思われます。ちなみにこんな記事 [x86 - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/X86) から大まかな歴史・経緯・発展過程を把握しておくと良いでしょう。

Comment: リセットベクタのあるチップと混同しているのかもしれません(ARMとか)。

Comment: 実は知りたいことの主題は後ろの段落の内容であって、それが直接には前の段落と結びつかない(関連が理解できない)からこの質問になっているのかもしれませんね。後段はこれらの記事が参考になるかも。[BIOSアップデート 【BIOS update】 BIOSアップグレード / BIOS upgrade](https://e-words.jp/w/BIOS%E3%82%A2%E3%83%83%E3%83%97%E3%83%87%E3%83%BC%E3%83%88.html), [旧BIOSを進化させたUEFI、その基本を解説（前編：役割と概要）](https://www.pc-koubou.jp/magazine/1257), [旧BIOSを進化させたUEFI、その基本を解説（後編：設定と確認）](https://www.pc-koubou.jp/magazine/1368) 前段はこちらの記事[Booting - Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Booting)の図の中間の部分の何かがリセットアドレスに飛ぶより前に行われているのかも？と感じていたのかもしれませんね。

Answer (score 5):

> 納得できないのは、CPUの初期信号を発行してから、BIOSの0xffff0を実行するまでの過程が書かれていないからです。どなたか、その間に何が起こっているのか教えてください。

何も起こっていません。[IA-32 インテル アーキテクチャ ソフトウェア・デベロッパーズ・マニュアル 下巻： システム・プログラミング・ガイド](https://www.intel.co.jp/content/dam/www/public/ijkk/jp/ja/documents/developer/IA32_Arh_Dev_Man_Vol3_i.pdf#page=369)には次のように記述されています。

> ### 第 9 章 プロセッサの管理と初期化
>
> #### 9.1. 初期化の概要
>
> ##### 9.1.4. 最初に実行される命令
>
> ハードウェア・リセット後にフェッチされてから実行される最初の命令は、物理アドレス FFFFFFF0H に配置される。このアドレスは、プロセッサの最上位にある物理アドレスの 16 バイト下に位置している。ソフトウェア初期化コードをストアしている EPROMは、このアドレスに配置されなければならない。

と説明されている通りです。CPUはハードウェア・リセットされた場合、物理アドレス FFFFFFF0H の命令を実行するように作られています。そのため、PCメーカーはこのアドレスにBIOSコードを配置する必要があります。
（コメントには000FFFF0Hと書きましたが、これは486辺りの知識で古かったです）

「ハードウェア・リセット」については[同書9.1](https://www.intel.co.jp/content/dam/www/public/ijkk/jp/ja/documents/developer/IA32_Arh_Dev_Man_Vol3_i.pdf#page=363)に

> 電源投入の後、またはRESET#ピンのアサーションの後、システムバス上の各プロセッサは、それぞれのハードウェアを初期化し（これをハードウェア・リセットと呼ぶ）、

と説明されています。

---

kunifさんのコメントより

> こんな情報 システムマネジメントモード - Wikipedia もあるので、理屈と言うかそう言いたい感覚は分かりますが、それを知ることが出来る/知っている必要があるのはインテルやx86互換CPUを開発するベンダーの関係者だけでしょう。

そんなことはありません。例に挙げておられますシステム管理モード（SMM: System Management Mode）についても[同書 第 13 章 システム管理](https://www.intel.co.jp/content/dam/www/public/ijkk/jp/ja/documents/developer/IA32_Arh_Dev_Man_Vol3_i.pdf#page=511)に34ページにわたって解説されています。一定の情報は公開されています。

本題のCPUの初期化部分に関しても

> ハードウェアのリセット後、最初に CS レジスタに新しい値がロードされると、プロセッサは、実アドレスモードでアドレス変換に適用される通常の規則に従う（つまり、[CSベースアドレス = CSセグメント・セレクタ∗16]）。EPROMベースのソフトウェア初期化コードが完了するまで CS レジスタ内のベースアドレスが変更されないようにするため、コードに far ジャンプまたは far コールを入れてはならない。

等、常識と言っても過言ではないレベルまで丁寧に説明されていますし、BIOSが起動後に行うべき処理についても[9.10. 初期化とモード切り替えの例](https://www.intel.co.jp/content/dam/www/public/ijkk/jp/ja/documents/developer/IA32_Arh_Dev_Man_Vol3_i.pdf#page=381)などで具体的なコード例も掲載されています。

これらを読んだと称する質問者さんが「納得できないのは、CPUの初期信号を発行してから、BIOSの0xffff0を実行するまでの過程が書かれていない」と書かれていますが、何に納得できないのか本当にわからないというのが正直なところです。

Comment: 蛇足ですが、私のコメントはシステムマネジメントモードそのものの事を言っているのではなく、自分の知識・理解が不十分な時にモードとかの覚えることが山のようにあると、見たままのことが素直に頭に入ってこなくて説明されていない/省略されている何かがあるのではないかと言う不安にかられる心の動きの事を言っています。また大分前からCPUは[マイクロアーキテクチャ - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%9E%E3%82%A4%E3%82%AF%E3%83%AD%E3%82%A2%E3%83%BC%E3%82%AD%E3%83%86%E3%82%AF%E3%83%81%E3%83%A3) によって構成された(内部の)CPUによってx86の命令セットがエミュレートされている風な動作をしているので、そのマイクロアーキテクチャCPUが起動/リセット時に何かを行っているのでは？みたいな発想が浮かんでいるのかもと想像しました。

Answer (score 0):

CPUにはプログラムカウンターまたはインストラクションポインターというレジスターがあります。
これは現在実行中の命令のアドレスを示しています。現在実行中の命令を実行し終わるとプログラムカウンターのアドレスは次の命令のアドレスに変更され、その値に従ってメモリーから命令が読み出され実行されます。これを繰り返してプログラムが動作することになります。
プログラムカウンターの値は命令がジャンプ命令等でなかった場合は、次の命令のアドレスになりますが、ジャンプ命令の場合はジャンプ先のアドレスになります。
リセット直後もこれと同様にプログラムは実行されますが、リセット直後はプログラムカウンターの値が特定の値になります。
これはCPUの種類により異なりますが、x86の場合は0xffff0となります。
このため最初に実行される命令を0xffff0に置く必要があります。
つまり、リセット直後特別なことをしているわけではなく、ただ単にプログラムカウンターの示すアドレスの命令を実行しているだけなのです。
リセット直後のプログラムカウンターの値はCPUにより0番地になるものや0番地に書かれたアドレスになるものもあります。
linuxやwindowsといったOSは通常ストレージに格納されており、ストレージからメモリにロードされて実行されます。この場合のメモリーは書き換え可能なRAMで無ければなりませんが、リセット直後の命令はRAMでは中身が不定ですので不揮発性のメモリ（ROM）である必要があります。