# 初期化後になんかやっているよね？そこからBIOS起動しているよね？

Tags: ハードウェア, bios

プロセッサー初期化 -> BSP(?) -> 謎のソフト -> BIOS

っていう流れでBIOSに起動しているのかな？
謎のソフトの所で、 in out命令でBIOSコードを読み込んでメモリーに取り込んでいるの？

それぞれのハードウェアを初期化し
それぞれのハードウェアとはなんですか？ BIOS上でメモリーコントロラーやPCIやFPUやグラフィックのやつなんかを初期化しなくてもいいよね？
でもPOSTを実行するながれは上記であげたハードウェアを初期化とエラーチェックみたいなんをしないとダメだよね？なんでやる必要があるの？

Comment: 例えば最近似たような質問がありました。[起動直後のCPUはどのようにしてBIOSにたどり着くのでしょうか？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/q/84075/26370) 何かの資料・書籍で理解できないことがあるとか、間違っているように見えるとかなら、それを明記して質問した方が助言・回答が付きやすいでしょう。こちらのヘルプ記事を参考に。[良い質問をするには？](https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) キーワード関連だとこんな記事があります。[Basic Input/Output System - Wikipedia](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_Input/Output_System), [Board support package - Wkikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Board_support_package)

Comment: in out命令でBIOSコードを読み込んでメモリーに取り込んでいるのではなく、メモリーフェッチによりBIOSのプログラムを読み込んでいます。これは通常のプログラムの実行と同じです。リセット後にはプログラムカウンターが初期化され、BIOSの最初の場所を示します。

Comment: 検索するとこんな資料 [x86 Initial Boot Sequence](https://alessandropellegrini.it/didattica/2017/aosv/1.Initial-Boot-Sequence.pdf) が見つかります。他にも色々あるでしょうから、そうしたものの内容を調べてみてはどうでしょう？

Comment: >  池田茂樹
iOSなどのソフトからBIOSコード読み書きのですか？　　またどのようにするの？

Answer (score 1):

PC(と呼ばれるハード)を前提にします

CPUには DRAM, ROM などが繋がっていて 指定のアドレスから実行可能
Power ON時に CPUは特定のアドレス(CPU種類によっては特定のベクター, など)から実行を開始する。その位置にはハード的に ROMが配置されている
ただし電源入ったすぐは ROM, SRAMはともかく DRAMは使えないので初期化が必要です

(DRAMについて)
Static RAM は CPUのレジスターやキャッシュなどにも使われていて, トランジスターの NOR ゲートを組み合わせた形。電流流れていれば使える
Dynamic RAM はコンデンサーが使われており, 電流流れててもそのうち放電し尽くし消える。のでメモリーコントローラーで, 読み込んだ内容を再度書き直す「リフレッシュ」が必要。起動時にはそのタイミングなどの指定がないと記憶できない (DRAM Frequency)

参考:

- SRAM https://tinystones.net/mem/mem5.html
- DRAM https://tinystones.net/mem/mem3.html

---

「BIOS」にはいくつかの意味が含まれていて, 以下の意味以外にもあるかも

1. BIOS: Basic Input/Output System のこと
2. 起動時の ROM のこと。BIOSはファームウェアとして中に含まれている
3. C-MOS のこと。ポタン電池でバックアップされた (CMOS SRAM 内の)情報

文字列出力, 文字列入力, ディスク I/O などの基本的な入出力は BIOS と呼ばれ, ROM 内にありサービスコールで呼び出すことが可能でした(過去形)
最近の？ CPUは 32ビットモードあるいは 64ビットモードで動作しているので, 16ビットのコードはそのままでは動きません
起動した OS 内の (必要とする) APIを呼び出すのが現在の形。OS側に, 必要な APIがすべて揃えてあるはず

画面が映るかキーボードが繋がっているかなどの POST (power-on self test: 電源投入時自己診断)も, 起動した OS の初期化処理で行うはずで, 先に ROMでも行うなら 2度手間に。
BIOS ROMに代わる次世代の起動方法では必要最小限の方向のはず (今でも, 数 GBの RAMのセルフチェックは時間かかるので省かれてるはず)
UEFIでは, BIOS-POST は ⇨ Pre-EFI初期化モジュール

参考:

- PDFドキュメント [新世代BIOS"UEFI"の構造と実装](https://ipsj.ixsq.nii.ac.jp/ej/?action=pages_view_main&active_action=repository_view_main_item_detail&item_id=62936&item_no=1&page_id=13&block_id=8)
- PDF [自由な PC 向けファームウェアの開発 --yabits: Yet Another UEFI Implementation―](https://www.ipa.go.jp/files/000065624.pdf)

  - (ja.wikipedia.org) [coreboot](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coreboot)

(2) の起動時 ROMについて
起動時 ROM (firmware)は, マスク ROMではなくフラッシュメモリーが使われてることが多い
これは (SSDなどでよく使われている)NAND型ではなく NOR型フラッシュメモリーで, 特徴としては ROM同様に普通にアドレス指定可能 (CPUの Jump命令, Call命令の飛び先に指定可能)
(なので, CPUから読み出して RAMに転送などの手順は必要ない)

Comment: DRAMの初期方法はメモリーをゼロ埋めする感じでしょうか。　それともどこかの制御用のレジスタをクリアする感じでしょうか？　　アドレス指定可能 (CPUの Jump命令, Call命令の飛び先に指定可能)　　と書かれているけどフラッシュメモリーは普通のメモリーの番地にジャンプする仕組みに似ているのでしょうか？

Comment: DRAM Frequencyの設定はメモリーコントローラーに対して行うはずです。それが終わるまで DRAMにアクセスしても意味がない。「数 GBの RAMのセルフチェック」は (行うとするなら) 何かを書き込んで読み取り, 内容確認を行ってるはず。NOR型フラッシュメモリーは「ROM同様に普通にアドレス指定可能」(電気的書き換え可能な ROMと捉えることが可能)です

Comment: 頭が混乱している　もう一度説明してくれないか　後、メモリーコントロラーはPCIというやつからいろいろいじったりするの？それか i/oピンから？　２つ？

Comment: Stack Overflowはコンピュータや情報技術, 特にプログラミング技術に関するナレッジコミュニティー(知識共有コミュニティー)です (「分からない」と駄々をこねれば回答が付く訳ではない)。質問の仕方の参考にどうぞ https://ja.stackoverflow.com/help

また, 知識共有コミュニティーなので, 第三者が同様の疑問を持った時に参照できるように記すのが望ましいでしょう (単に「分からない」ではなく, 「どのように」「どういった点について」あるいは「この様に考えたが違うのか」とか)

Answer (score 0):

何を訊きたいのか微妙に（というより全く）わからないのですが、「初期化」という単語をどうとらえているか、あなたと読者の間で合意が成立しないと回答しても無駄な努力で終わるというか。

> それぞれのハードウエア

PCを構成する各種要素のことです。例えば DIMM 例えば PCI-e カード例えばキーボード

DIMM を挿入せずに、あるいは挿入不完全で接触不良状態で電源を投入したら PC から見て主記憶装置が存在しません。あるいは DIMM に不良があって/オーバークロックのし過ぎで CPU から見て正しく読み書き操作に反応しないなんてこともありそうです。

あるいは何か部品を入れ替えたりすることで OS を起動するべき大容量記憶装置が変わったり消滅したりすることもあるでしょう。

> BIOS上でメモリーコントロラーやPCIやFPUやグラフィックのやつなんかを初期化しなくてもいいよね？

各種部品（ボード類）が与えられた信号に反応するようになる＝そのボードの自己初期化は当然行われる前提で（質問者氏のいう初期化はこれのことだとオイラは想像する）でも PC １台の初期化はそれだけでは不足で、全体の構成がどうなっているのか把握するとか、不良な部品がないかどうかとか、そういうののチェックは BIOS (UEFI) レベルで行わないと OS の起動までたどり着くことはできないでしょう（PC/BIOS の初期化というのはこっち）

OS の起動以前の話として、今時の PC はディスプレイが複数個ついているものが普通で、どのディスプレイにどの解像度で POST 画面を出すのかなんてのも BIOS レベルで存在認識・表示優先度の確認・出力先の解像度設定なんてのもやらないとユーザーが困る。